# HTML "body onload" only works when manually refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a JS function that should execute with onload in HTML. The function does not run when arriving on the page, only when I refresh the browser. I have the same problem locally and on the published website.

In html I have :

```
<body class="theme-light" data-background="none" data-highlight="red2" onload="myRequest()">
```

And in JS:

```js
    const myRequest = () => {
      const seasonProductSelector = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);  
      let inputValue = getSeasonalProductsArray(n)[seasonProductSelector];
      let url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?apiKey=**************&query='+inputValue+'&number=1';
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();  
      };
```

I know the function itself works fine, when I manually refresh the page. But it won't run upon the page loading the first time.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how do you navigate to the page? do you click a link on the website? maybe the link/navigation is handled using Javascript.

Comment: any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: what if you add this to the javascript and remove the onload from the body? `window.on('load', function(){
      myRequest();
      });`

Comment: Try to create a script inside the html of that page with a document ready and the function you have.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for your answers. Turns out the template I'm using requires to place JS in a specific file for it to work.